# VB6 - Game won't work

Tags: vb6

-I'm a noob at VB6 and I just need to know what I'm doing wrong in my code
I want the mouse to click on a picturebox in the form which will in turn
execute code depending on the circumstances

Here's my code:

```
Dim MineTotalHits As Integer
Dim MineTotal As Integer
Dim EmptySquare As Integer
Dim MineTotalMisses As Integer
Dim WinSnd As Boolean
Dim MinesInRow As Integer
Dim ShellCount As Integer
Dim MaxMines As Integer
Dim MinesLeft As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Snd.Hide
    Start.Show

    Dim Count(1 To 10) As Integer
    Dim RowMines(1 To 10) As Label

    EmptySquare = 50
    MaxMines = 50
    ShellCount = 90
    MinesLeft = 50
    MineTotal = 0
    MineTotalHits = 0
    MineTotalMisses = 0

    Do Until MineTotal = MaxMines
        Randomize (Int(99 * Rnd + 1))
        MineTotal = MineTotal + 1
    Loop      
End Sub


Public Sub WinGame(WinSnd As Boolean)
    Dim IntResponse As Integer

    If MinesLeft = 0 Then
        WinSnd = True
        MsgBox ("You have won the Game")
        IntResponse = MsgBox("Would You like to play a New Game?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion, "NewGame?")

        If IntResponse = vbYes = 1 Then
            Snd.Show
        ElseIf IntResponse = vbNo = 2 Then
            Unload Me
        End If

    ElseIf ShellCount = 0 Then
        WinSnd = False
        MsgBox ("You have lost the Game")
        IntResponse = MsgBox("Would you Like to play a New Game?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion, "NewGame?")

        If IntResponse = vbYes = 1 Then
            Snd.Show
        ElseIf IntResponse = vbNo = 2 Then
            Unload Me
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Picture1_Click(Index As Integer)
    Dim Picture1(99) As PictureBox
End Sub

Private Sub MouseDown(Button As Integer, Index As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Button = 1 Then Call MouseDown
        If Picture1(99) = MinesLeft Then
            MsgBox ("You have destroyed a mine")
            MineTotalHits = MineTotalHits + 1
            MinesLeft = MinesLeft - 1
            Picture1(Index).BackColor = vbBlack

        ElseIf Picture1(99) = EmptySquare Then
            MsgBox ("You have missed a mine")
            EmptySquare = EmptySquare - 1
            MineTotalMisses = MineTotalMisses + 1
            Picture1(Index).BackColor = vbRed
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Picture1().BackColor = vbBlack Or Picture1().BackColor = vbRed Then
        MsgBox ("This Square has already been hit")

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: And yet people still answer COBOL questions :-)

Comment: @Wyzard, passing judgement on a language choice is just noise. Please refrain from doing that - the question is about VB6, and your personal feelings about that language are irrelevant. This isn't a chat room. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite, this is a place to give advice and guidance.  Sometimes good advice and guidance includes things the asker didn't know they needed to know.

Comment: @Wyzard, so it's appropriate for me to mention that you've spelled `Wizard` incorrectly? No, it's irrelevant, because you didn't ask me how to spell. :-) As I said, this is not a discussion site or chat room; there are flags for `noise` comments for a reason.

Comment: I've no VB6 IDe to hand, but does this even compile?

Comment: from ancient memory at least  IntResponse = MsgBox("Would you Like to play a New Game?")

        vbYesNo vbQuestion, ("NewGame?")
needs to be  IntResponse = MsgBox("Would you Like to play a New Game?", vbYesNo or vbQuestion, "NewGame?")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly read the [FAQ] -- Stack Overflow is not a debugging nor a training service. How can you cause `the mouse to click on a picturebox in the form` -- isn't that something the user has to do manually?

Answer (score 4):

In VB6, event handlers take the form of SourceObject_EventName.  Your MouseDown does not conform to this.